# BigQuery - Service availability

Tags: google-bigquery

Google BigQuery ensures a minimum availability of its service?

Given the eventual failure of any component in Google's infrastructure, might happen to lose some or all information I have uploaded?
How Google can ensure data availability even if a failure occurs?

I mean what happens if a node (server) goes down? What happens to data that is stored on it? And if fail 10 or 100 nodes? What would have to happen for that service becomes unavailable?

I am researching on the availability of this platform and what mechanisms has to be fault-tolerant

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BigQuery has a 99.9% monthly uptime SLA.

Check https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/sla for details.

The whole system is based on a highly replicated fault tolerant architecture, but not all details from it are made public.

If you also need 24x7 fast phone and email support, you can get it. Details at https://cloud.google.com/support/packages.